# Hidden overflow not working on image

Tags: html, css

I have tried using overflow: hidden; for each element but it does not seem to be doing anything

The html looks like this, the display is to have the 2 divs side by side (stacks ontop for smaller screens). The left side div will also be on top of the right side div. I have a screen shot and fiddle too.

```css
.sec {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sec2 {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img1 {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.img1 {
  z-index: 1;
}

.leftCol {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 50%;
}

.info-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

.rightCol {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="sec">
  <div class="info-row">
    <div class="leftCol info-column">
      <h1>haheaheh</h1>
      <p>teataetetat</p>
    </div>
    <div class='rightCol info-column'>
      <img class="img1" src='https://kasonbloom.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/lamb-2.jpg' />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="sec2">
  <div class="info-row">
    <div class="leftCol info-column">
      <h1>asdfasdfasdf</h1>
      <p>basfbasdfbasdfba</p>
    </div>
    <div class='rightCol info-column'>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/gtrnrd9r/2/ keep result view at a point where the image breaks through the section

Comment: In your `section` CSS, `minHeight` should be `min-height` and `paddingTop` should be `padding-top`. And please, try to have consistent indents.

Comment: i'm not sure where you are seeing I have minHeight and paddingTop, but i reposted the fiddle with tidy indents

Comment: I was saying that about the code you posted here, not the fiddle. ;)

Comment: oh sorry, I converted it front react styles to regular styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add `position:relative;` to your outer section `.sec` and it will work fine.

```css
.sec {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}

.sec2 {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img1 {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.img1 {
 z-index: 1;

}

.leftCol {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 50%;
}

.info-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 10vw;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

.rightCol {
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section class="sec">
  <div class="info-row">
    <div class="leftCol info-column">
      <h1>haheaheh</h1>
      <p>teataetetat</p>
    </div>
    <div class='rightCol info-column'>
      <img class="img1" src='https://kasonbloom.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/lamb-2.jpg' />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="sec2">
  <div class="info-row">
    <div class="leftCol info-column">
      <h1>asdfasdfasdf</h1>
      <p>basfbasdfbasdfba</p>

    </div>
    <div class='rightCol info-column'>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, i spent more time than id like to admit trying to solve this

Answer (score 0):

.rightCol needs his own width and height if i'm not mistaken. overflow doesn't work with the parent element.